# undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass with bcrypt-ruby and has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going through DHH's Agile Web Development with Rails for Rails 3.1.  In chapter 14 they create a Users sign-in model/view/controller using the has_secure_password method.  My user.rb file looks like this:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
      validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      has_secure_password
    end
```

now when I go to localhost:3000/users/new I first get some kind of bcrypt-ruby error and then when I reload the page I get a undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

I don't know what needs to be done,
mike

Comment: I think you'd get answers on the forums of this resource (http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/148). I think this is too localized for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured out what happened.  I installed bcrypt-ruby and ran bundle install but never restarted the server.  Everything's working now.