# NoMethodError in UsersController#show / undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've encountered an unexpected error while following Michael Hartl's *Rails Tutorial*. It had been smooth sailing.

I first saw that I was getting a different "Action Controller: Exception caught" error than the Tutorial following the completion of [Hartl's Listing 7.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up.html#code-users_resource).

Specifically, when trying to reach /users/1, I get:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#show
>
> undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

I continued on through Listing 7.5 - adding a view for for a User's show action and then adding the show action to the Users controller - which resolved the error Hartl was getting, but these steps didn't resolve my error.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440325/rails-3-2-undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass), I've verified that my app/models/user.rb is free of typos: after scouring it for typos, I copied & pasted Hartl's code into my file for good measure.

Any guidance on where else to look for typos/issues would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** As requested, the UsersController#show method:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**EDIT 2:** Full trace:

> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
>
> journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
>
> journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
>
> journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
>
> activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
>
> activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
>
> activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3560654018285941260__call__3098371293035639072__callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>
> activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>
> activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
>
> railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
>
> activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
>
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
>
> railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
>
> rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
>
> /Users/aaronmacy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
>
> /Users/aaronmacy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
>
> /Users/aaronmacy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'

**EDIT 3:** users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { self.email.downcase! }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

Comment: Is the rest of the backtrace available?  Are you sure this error is associated with the line number of the find statement?  What happens if you do User.find(1) in the console?

Comment: @jordanpg No, not sure. If I enter User.find(1) in the console it finds the User with :id => 1. I'm about to add the full trace to the question...

Comment: This doesn't look like it is the whole thing.  There should be a couple of more lines, at least one of which references users_controller.rb.  Something like this:  `activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in 'method_missing'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in 'show'`

Comment: @jordanpg I just double checked. That's all of it.

Comment: Then more information is needed.  Let's see routes.rb, users_controller.rb, and user.rb to start.

Comment: @jordanpg added! Thanks for sticking with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bcrypt issue.  Verify that you have uncommented bcrypt in your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and then restarted the server.

See:  [undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass with bcrypt-ruby and has_secure_password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568316/undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass-with-bcrypt-ruby-and-has-secure-passwor)

Comment: Great, thanks! FWIF, I had bcrypt, uncommented, in my Gemfile & I'd run `bundle install`. I guess I hadn't restarted the server since then... so basically I just had to restart the server. D'oh.