# Saving binary data using MongoID in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

This seems like it should be straightforward and work.  MongoDB / BSON have a native binary type, and the Moped driver supports it.  But when I try to create a scaffold in my rails project

```
rails g scaffold image png:binary source:string
```

I get this model:

```
class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :png, type: Binary
  field :source, type: String
end
```

which generates this error:

```
uninitialized constant Image::Binary
```

Using Rails 3.2.8 and Mongoid 3.0.9.

Comment: It doesn't seem like mongoid supports the `Binary` type: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields
Can you please try changing `Binary` to `BSON::Binary`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to use the `Moped::BSON::Binary` type:

```
class Image
  ...
   # mongoid version <= v3 
  field :png, type: Moped::BSON::Binary
   # mongoid version >= v4 
  field :png, type: BSON::Binary
end


i = Image.new
# mongoid version <= v3 
i.png = Moped::BSON::Binary.new(:generic, <image data> ) 

# mongoid version >= v4 
i.png = BSON::Binary.new(:generic, <image data> )
```

Comment: Thanks -- this makes the model work, but the view is still busted.

Comment: Found the solution to my subsequent problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791545/nomethoderror-in-userscontrollershow-undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass

Comment: Great! Would you be willing to accept this answer? (and sorry for referencing the wrong field)

Comment: Cheers! I've also [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.github.com/pull/3) to update the [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields) with the `Moped::BSON::Binary` type.

Comment: A minor nitpick: for mongoid >= v4 you switched the order of parameters. The correct order is: `BSON::Binary.new(<data>, :generic)`